# Why are some glyphs missing from the text when using a custom font?

Tags: css, windows, fonts

So this is a problem I have on a site I'm developing, but I included a screenshot from the Google Fonts web site, because it's public and everyone can look at it and it's also clear it's not something specific to my code.

The screenshot was taken on a Windows 7 virtual machine running IE9. It's the virtual machine from https://dev.modern.ie, so there shouldn't be anything special about it either.

And finally, this is the Fira Sans font, but this same issue has happened to me before with the Lato font on another (Windows) machine, so it shouldn't be the font either.

If you open the page — https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Fira+Sans — it will probably look just fine on your machine, as it does on mine. I can only reproduce it on the VM.

Here's how it looks in IE9:
[image: A screenshot showing the missing glyphs issue.]

In Chrome all glyphs are missing, so all of the text that is using the font is not rendered at all.
In Firefox the rendering is a little ugly, somewhat pixelated, but at least all of the glyphs are there and it's almost alright.

I tried deleting `C:\Windows\System32\FNTCACHE.DAT` and some font-related .dat file in
`C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\Appdata\Local`, but it made no difference.

At this point I have absolutely no idea what's going on. Do you have any idea what might be causing this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What page is that screenshot from? Your link points to slightly different page. There _are_ problems with the page; in my VirtualBox (Windows 7, same as yours), IE9 is not loading the font. All the text is displayed, but in the default font. Everything looks all right under Chrome and PaleMoon however.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! At least I know it's not just me, although it sounds like a slightly different problem. Weird.  I can't link to the original screenshot's page, because it doesn't have a real URL. To get there from the page I linked to, you have to select “Open Fira Sans in Google Fonts »” in the upper right corner of the page I linked to and then choose “Review” (lower right). Sorry about that. However, at least on my VM it's absolutely the same on the page I linked to in the OP, so it shouldn't matter too much.

Comment: Here's a side-by-side of the linked page opened on the VM in IE9 and on my machine in Chrome: http://i.imgur.com/UO029lM.png

Comment: Interesting. If I go to "Open..." and "Review", IE9 shows the font normally. So it does get loaded. Back to the first page and it still uses the default font. No missing characters though! [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gTrnk.jpg) with IE9, Chrome, Pale Moon and SeaMonkey native.

Comment: I think in your case IE9 is still not using the font. The font in the left most window (IE9) is a serif. It looks like Georgia, but I'm not sure. What I think happens is IE9 still doesn't load the font and is using the default serif this time. I have no idea why it's not using the default sans-serif or why it's not loading the font in the first place. The font in the other 3 is correct. The ugly, slightly pixelated rendering in Pale Moon corresponds to how it looks in Firefox, which is to be expected. So all in all, it looks like a different problem, but thanks for your help anyway!